# minimal amount of operations needed to construct a line segment of length n

Tags: geometry

The line segment of unit length is given. $ C(n)$ is minimal amount of 
operations  needed  to  construct  a  line  segment  of  length  $n$ via  just 
compass, $CR(n)$ - via compass and ruler. Prove that $C(n)/CR(n)$ is 
unbounded.

Comment: Please remind us how to do it with just a compass.

Comment: wish i knew the meaning

Comment: user, are you replying to my comment? If you want to ensure that I see a reply to a comment of mine, you have to put @Gerry into it. Anyway, the meaning of my comment is, you write, "$C(n)$ is minimal amount of operations needed to construct a line segment of length $n$ via just compass," and I want to know how you construct a line segment of length $n$ via just compass.

Comment: What's the domain of $n$? Because for some $n\in\mathbb R$, both numbers are obviously undefined as some numbers simply cannot be constructed given these tools.

Comment: @MvG -  n∈N, and we need to show that the number of operations to build a line length  n by compass only, is increasing faster than the number of operation to build by compass and ruler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a negative result for one approach.

In your comment you suggest that you're mostly interested in the asymptotic behaviour $\lim_{n\to\infty}$. Suppose you describe your construction for large $n$ iteratively, i.e. starting with the construction for length $n$, it will construct a segment of length $f(n)$ using a given set of steps, and $f(f(n))$ using the same steps over again with $f(n)$ as the starting point. In this approach each individual construction has a *fixed number of steps*.

I guess that the maximal increase in length should be quadratic: using von Staudt constructions you can multiply two numbers in a fixed number of steps in projective geometry, and it should be possible to do the same in Euclidean geometry. So you would have $f(n)\in\mathcal O(n^2)$, but even a faster-growing $f$ might exist, as long as each application of that function corresponds to a fixed number of constructin steps.

Now there is the [Mohr-Mascheroni theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr%E2%80%93Mascheroni_theorem), which states that any construction which you can perform using compass and straightedge can be constructed using compass alone. I don't know the details about how this can be done. But as there is no absolute unit of length in Euclidean geometry, the number of compass operations required to construct $f(n)$ given $n$ cannot depend on the value of $n$. Instead, the number of steps required for this *has to be fixed* as well. So you can construct each application of $f$ using a fixed number of steps using one set of tools, and using a different but equally fixed number of steps using the other technique. The asymptotic limit would simply be the ratio between these two numbers.

So far, this looks like a contradiction to the thing you want to proove. There are however some assumptions which sound reasonable but might be unjustified. It might be that the problems are not in the $n\to\infty$ limit, but for some $n$ with a particularly difficult structure. Prime numbers would be a likely candidate. Or it might be that there is a way to construct ever-growing segments where each increase in length is not accomplished by a fixed number of operations. I can't think of one such way just now, but there might be.

Comment: i tried by induction, didn't figure how.
thanks for your great comment!